# Appending UnicodeString to WideString in Delphi

Tags: delphi, unicode-string, widestring

I'm curious about what happens with this piece of code in Delphi 2010:

```
function foo: WideString;
var 
   myUnicodeString: UnicodeString; 
begin
  for i:=1 to 1000 do
  begin
    myUnicodeString := ... something ...;

    result := result + myUnicodeString;  // This is where I'm interested
  end;
end;
```

How many string conversions are involved, and are any particularly bad performance-wise?

I know the function should just return a `UnicodeString` instead, but I've seen this anti-pattern in the VCL streaming code, and want to understand the process.

Comment: Did you try to look that up in the debugger's CPU window?

Comment: @OnTheFly: It's actually part of a C++ Builder project, and for some reason BCB2010 doesn't like setting breakpoints in the VCL code... I'll try stepping through some more.

Comment: If you dont have Delphi to study the generated code for your tescase, I can post a disassembly, but I'm really unsure how to present it in the useful form...

Comment: @Roddy: Check the linker option to use debug DCUs. (Project->Options->Delphi Compiler->Use Debug DCUs). This will allow you to step into the Delphi VCL and RTL from Builder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer your question about what the code is actually doing, this statement:

```
result := result + myUnicodeString;
```

Does the following:

1. calls `System._UStrFromWStr()` to convert `Result` to a temp `UnicodeString`
2. calls `System._UStrCat()` to concatenate `myUnicodeString` onto the temp
3. calls `System._WStrFromUStr()` to convert the temp to a `WideString` and assign it back to `Result`.

There is a `System._WStrCat()` function for concatenating a `WideString` onto a `WideString` (and `System._UStrCat()` for `UnicodeString`).  If CodeGear/Embarcadero had been smarter about it, they could have implemented a `System._WStrCat()` overload that takes a `UnicodeString` as input and a `WideString` as output (and vice versa for concatenating a `WideString` onto a `UnicodeString`). That way, no temp `UnicodeString` conversions would be needed anymore.  Both `WideString` and `UnicodeString` are encoded as UTF-16 (well mostly, but I won't get into that here), so concatenating them together is just a matter of a single allocation and move, just like when concatenating two `UnicodeString`s or two `WideString`s together.

Comment: Thanks Remy. That explains lots!

Answer (score 4):

The performance is poor. There's no need for any encoding conversions since everything is UTF-16 encoded. However, WideString is a wrapper around the COM BSTR type which performs worse than native UnicodeString.

Naturally you should prefer to do all your work with the native types, either UnicodeString or TStringBuilder, and convert to WideString at the last possible moment.

That is generally a good policy. You don't want to use WideString internally since it's purely an interop type. So only convert to (and from) WideString at the interop boundary.

Comment: Thanks. I'm particularly curious as to whether the string concat (wide := wide + uni) happens in the unicode or wide domain. If it's unicode, then two conversions are involved. (wide->uni, concat, uni->wide)

Comment: I don't know that specific detail off the top of my head. But it's trivially easy to work out with a debugger. Something I don't have right now. Either way, you don't want it. Do all your work with TStringBuilder and convert to WideString as late as possible. All those concatenations would be bad even with pure native strings. Heavy on the heap.

Comment: It's not actually my code. It's in classes.pas in D2010 (CombineWideString). I had an issue where a form with a single 4MB string property (yes, but there's a good reason!) took 2.5 minutes(!) to load when using text DFMs, and under a second with binary.

Comment: You can't do anything about it then. You know the performance is rubbish. Just don't put the string in the dfm file.

Comment: Actually, you can do something about it.  Modify Classes.pas (the offending code is in the `implementation` section) and add the modified file to your project so it will override the RTL's default code. This only works if the project is not using runtime packages, though.

Comment: @Remy You can't do anything easily. The comment about text dfms makes it clear this is a design time issue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: actually, it is not a design-time issue at all. He's using DFMs to stream custom data files at runtime. [See this discussion](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=91138). So my earlier comment still stands. Edit `Classes.pas` to fix the performance problem (it was natively fixed by Embarcadero in XE3) and add the edited file to the project.

Comment: @Remy Fair enough. I was lacking that background info. Obviously, with standard .dfm files associated with forms and data modules, then text .dfm is only design time.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Thanks for your input - I should have linked to my forum post. IIRC, If you use text DFMs they're linked into the final exe as text RCDATA resources, so it's potentially an issue just with that.

Comment: @Roddy I don't think so. Text DFM setting is just for the source. The linked executable always has binary DFMs.

Comment: You're right, as usual. XN Resource editor automatically displays them as though they were text, which caught me out...